# $scope in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I realize a graphical interface. To make these graphs we need datas. So, I have made a file containing my datas, with a $scope in a controller :

```
'use strict'
angular.module('gestionPrj')
.controller('ProjetsCtrl',function($scope)
{
    $scope.mesProjets=[
        {id:1, name_folder:'aeff', date:'2010', country:'Germany', quantity:256},
        {id:2, name_folder:'Technologies', date:'2012',country:'Russia', quantity:21},
        {id:3, name_folder:'Déosciences',date:'1989', country:'France', quantity:660},
        {id:4, name_folder:'Mises à jour', date:'2000', country:'China', quantity:47},
    ];
    $scope.filtreProjet="";
});
```

Here is a file that calls other files that contain graphics . This is the main file to build the interface :

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%">
<div id="titre">GRAPHICAL SEARCH </div>
    <div class="mobile-nav">

        <ul>
            <li><a id="outside" class="open-menu" href="#"><i class="ion ion-grid"></i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="row" ng-controller="PerformanceDataController">
                <div id="graph1"> <!--lm modif : avant c'était : <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">-->
                    <div class="panel panel-dashboard">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                                    <div class="controls left"></div>
                                    <div class="controls right"><a class="remove"></a></div>
                                    <div class="center" style="font-size: 15px">Folder filter 
                                            <label><!--<input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" value="checkbox2" style="right:150%">--><input type="image" src="refresh.png" id="reset1" onClick="reset_folder_filter()" value="Reset" href="lien">
                                            </label> <!--lm modif : pour mettre une checkbox et un petit bouton reset en dessous du graphique-->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">

                                <!--<div class="huge" style="min-width:90%;max-width: 90%" >-->
                                <!--<IFRAME src="var/www/html/interfaceUnique/ipMetrix/tools/Specific_Studies/tests/js/testBubble.php" style="width:90%; height:300px"></IFRAME>-->
                                <!--<IFRAME src="http://192.168.1.182/interfaceUnique/ipMetrix//tools/Specific_Studies/tests/testBubble.php" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width:90%; height:300px"></IFRAME>-->
                                <IFRAME src="http://192.168.1.182/interfaceUnique/ipMetrix//tools/Specific_Studies/tests/testBubbleessai.php" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width:90%; height:300px"></IFRAME>
                                <!--</div>-->
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div id="graph2"> <!--lm modif : avant c'était <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">-->
                    <div class="panel panel-dashboard">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                                    <div class="controls left"></div>
                                    <div class="controls right"><a class="remove"></a></div>
                                    <div class="center" style="font-size: 15px">Date filter 
                                            <label><!--<input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" value="checkbox2" style="right:150%">--><input type="image" src="refresh.png" id="reset2" onClick="reset_date_filter()" value="Reset" href="lien">
                                            </label> <!--lm modif : pour mettre une checkbox et un petit bouton reset en dessous du graphique-->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <!--<IFRAME src="http://192.168.1.182/interfaceUnique/ipMetrix/tools/Specific_Studies/tests/SitePointTutorialFinalAngularClient-masterTEST/barchart/barchart.html" style="width:90%; height:300px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></IFRAME>-->
                                <div id="container" style="width:90%; height:300px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></div>
                                <!--<div id="chart-container2" style="min-width:90%;max-width: 90%"></div> --> <!--lm modif : avant c'était <div class="huge">{{netInData}}</div>--><!--lm modif : chart-container se trouve dans "controller.js", c'est pour faire le barchart-->
                                <div class="clearfix"></div> 
                                <!--<div> <h5 style="color:rgb(220,0,0);font-size:12px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:0px"><b><i>To activate a filter, click the legend below the graph</b></i></h5></div>-->
                                <!--lm modif : début pour mettre les curseurs-->
                                <form oninput="output1.value=parseInt(slider1.value)+1960;output2.value=parseInt(slider2.value)+1960">
                                    <input type="range" name="slider1" class="mySlider" min="0" max="56" value="0" />
                                    <output name="output1" id="output1" for="slider1" style="font-size:10px;padding-top:0px;text-align:left">1960</output>
                                    <br />
                                    <input type="range" name="slider2" class="mySlider" min="0" max="56" value="56" />
                                    <output name="output2" id="output2" for="slider2" style="font-size:10px;padding-top:0px;text-align:right">2016</output>
                                </form>
                                <!--lm modif : fin pour mettre les curseurs-->
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="graph3"> <!--lm modif : avant c'était <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">-->
                    <div class="panel panel-dashboard">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                                    <div class="controls left"></div>
                                    <div class="controls right"><a class="remove"></a></div>
                                    <div class="center" style="font-size: 15px">Expression filter
                                            <label><!--<input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" value="checkbox2" style="right:150%">--><input type="image" src="refresh.png" id="reset3" onClick="reset_expression_filter()" value="Reset" href="lien">
                                            </label> <!--lm modif : pour mettre une checkbox et un petit bouton reset en dessous du graphique-->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="panel-body" id="test" >
                                <IFRAME src="http://192.168.1.182/interfaceUnique/ipMetrix/tools/Specific_Studies/tests/SitePointTutorialFinalAngularClient-masterTEST/treemap/Jit/Examples/Treemap/example1.html" style="width:90%; height:300px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></IFRAME>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div id="graph4"> <!--lm modif : <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">-->
                    <div class="panel panel-dashboard">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                                    <div class="controls left"></div>
                                    <div class="controls right"><a class="remove"></a></div>
                                    <div class="center" style="font-size: 15px">Keyword filter 
                                             <label><!--<input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" value="checkbox2" style="right:150%">--><input type="image" src="refresh.png" id="reset4" onClick="reset_keyword_filter()" value="Reset" href="lien">
                                            </label> <!--lm modif : pour mettre une checkbox et un petit bouton reset en dessous du graphique-->
                                    </div>                                   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="panel-body" >
                                <IFRAME src="http://192.168.1.182/interfaceUnique/ipMetrix/tools/Specific_Studies/tests/SitePointTutorialFinalAngularClient-masterTEST/expression/index.html" style="width:90%; height:300px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></IFRAME>

                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->


            <!-- /.row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div id="graph5"> <!--lm modif : avant c'était <div class="col-lg-8">-->
                    <div class="panel panel-dashboard">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                                    <div class="controls left"></div>
                                    <div class="controls right"><a class="remove"></a></div>
                                    <div class="center" style="font-size: 15px">Country filter 
                                            <label><!--<input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" value="checkbox2" style="right:150%">--><input type="image" src="refresh.png" id="reset5" onClick="reset_country_filter()" value="Reset" href="lien">
                                            </label> <!--lm modif : pour mettre une checkbox et un petit bouton reset en dessous du graphique-->
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-heading -->

                        <div class="panel-body">
                        <div id="chart-container5" style="min-width:90%;max-width: 90%;"></div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                             <!--lm modif : avant c'était <div class="huge">{{netInData}}</div>--><!--lm modif : chart-container se trouve dans "controller.js", c'est pour faire le barchart-->
                        <!--lm modif : pour faire une liste déroulante de tous les pays :-->
                            <select id="liste_déroulante" class=form-control style="width:auto;font-size: 10px;height:auto; margin-left:60px">
                                <option value=Choose>---Choose a continent or a country---</option>
                                <option value=Continent>---Choose a continent---</option>
                                <option id="continent1" value=Afrique>Afrique</option>
                                <option id="continent2" value=Amérique>Amérique</option>
                                <option id="continent3" value=Asie>Asie</option>
                                <option id="continent4" value=Europe>Europe</option>
                                <option id="continent5" value=Océanie>Océanie</option>
                                <option value=Country>---Choose a country---</option>
                                <option id="Pays1" value=Arizona>Arizona</option>
                                <option id="Pays2" value=Utha>Utha</option>
                                <option id="Pays3" value=France>France</option>
                                <option id="Pays4" value=Allemagne>Allemagne</option>
                                <option id="Pays5" value=Alaska>Alaska</option>
                                <option id="Pays6" value=Indiana>Indiana</option>
                                <option id="Pays7" value=Angleterre>République Démocratique du Congo</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>


                        <!-- /.panel-body -->
                    </div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel -->
                <div id="graph6"> <!--lm modif : avant il n'y avait rien-->
                    <div class="panel panel-dashboard">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                                    <div class="controls left"></div>
                                    <div class="controls right"><a class="remove"></a></div>
                                    <div class="center" style="font-size: 15px">Author filter
                                    <label><!--<input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" value="checkbox2" style="right:150%">--><input type="image" src="refresh.png" id="reset6" value="Reset" href="lien">
                                            </label> <!--lm modif : pour mettre une checkbox et un petit bouton reset en dessous du graphique-->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <IFRAME src="http://192.168.1.182/interfaceUnique/ipMetrix/tools/Specific_Studies/tests/SitePointTutorialFinalAngularClient-masterTEST/tableau.html" style="width:90%; height:300px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" ></IFRAME>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-body -->
                    </div>

</div>
                    <!-- /.panel -->
                <div id="graph7"> <!--lm modif : avant il n'y avait rien-->
                    <div class="panel panel-dashboard">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                                    <div class="huge">{{currentRamNumber}}</div>
                                    <div class="controls left"></div>
                                    <div class="controls right"><a class="remove"></a></div>
                                    <div class="center" style="font-size: 15px">Organization filter
                                            <label><!--<input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" value="checkbox2" style="right:150%">--><input type="image" src="refresh.png" id="reset7" value="Reset" href="lien">
                                            </label> <!--lm modif : pour mettre une checkbox et un petit bouton reset en dessous du graphique-->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                        <div class="panel-body">
                                <IFRAME src="http://192.168.1.182/interfaceUnique/ipMetrix/tools/Specific_Studies/tests/SitePointTutorialFinalAngularClient-masterTEST/tableauorganizations.html" style="width:90%; height:300px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" ></IFRAME>

                                <div class="clearfix"></div>


                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-body -->
                    </div>

                    <!-- /.panel -->
                <!-- /.col-lg-8 -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-8 -->

                <div id="graph8"> <!--lm modif : avant c'était <div class="col-lg-4">-->
                    <div class="panel panel-dashboard">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                                    <div class="huge">{{currentRamNumber}}</div>
                                    <div class="controls left"></div>
                                    <div class="controls right"><a class="remove"></i></a></div>
                                    <div class="center" style="font-size: 15px">Collaboration filter
                                            <label><!--<input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" value="checkbox2" style="right:150%">--><input type="image" src="refresh.png" id="reset8" onClick="reset_collaboration_filter()" value="Reset" href="lien">
                                            </label> <!--lm modif : pour mettre une checkbox et un petit bouton reset en dessous du graphique-->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div ng-controller="PerformanceDataController">
                                <iframe src="http://192.168.1.182/interfaceUnique/ipMetrix/tools/Specific_Studies/tests/SitePointTutorialFinalAngularClient-masterTEST/networkMika/index.html" svg="svgcontainer" style="width:90%; height:300px" scrolling="no" frameborder="1"></iframe>
                                <!--<img src="network.png" style="min-width:90%;max-width: 90%"> <!--lm modif : avant c'était <pie-chart data="data" options="options"></pie-chart>-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-body -->
                    </div>



                        </div>

                        <!-- /.panel-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel -->


                    </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->

            </div>

            <!-- /.row -->
        </div>

        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

    </div>
</div>
```

Now, to build the graphs, we have to call the $scope to the creation of each graphics. How do this please ?

Comment: You want to show in your HTML the data from `$scope.mesProjets`?

Comment: This huge piece of html code looks like a cover up. WHAT HAVE YOU TRIED?

Comment: yes actually I want to call my data in each file that creates a chart

Comment: In fact, I have a graphical interface. Each graph is made with fictional datas. Now, I want centralize datas in a controller, and call the $scope to take the real datas.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add `ProjetsCtrl` controller in your view, so that you can access data bind to `ProjetsCtrl` controller and then you can use ng-repeat directive like this.

```
<div ng-controller = 'ProjetsCtrl'>
    <div ng-repeat = 'mesProjet in mesProjets'>
        <div>{{mesProjet.id}}</div>
        <div>{{mesProjet.name}}</div>
        <div>{{mesProjet.country}}</div>
        <div>{{mesProjet.date}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Its look like you are very new to angularjs. You can follow this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKkUN-mJtPQ&list=PL6n9fhu94yhWKHkcL7RJmmXyxkuFB3KSl to get started with angularjs

Comment: Thank you for the link !

I have a file "Index.php" which is the rendering of the graphical interface.
I have a file "controller.js" which contains all the graphs made with fusioncharts and highcharts.
I have files .php for all the graphs. And now the file controller.js. 

Wher can I put your code ?

Comment: Inside html in index.php

Comment: I am very sorry, but wher in the code ?
In each div of graph ? At the end? The beggining ?